# Reading a input email address from html and using in JSP scriplet

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Hi I have an html field that takes an email.  I would like to take the entered value and ensure it exists in the database before proceeding.

```
<script>
function updateUserData()
{
document.getElementById(picker_email).value;
alert( "INVALID EMAIL ");
}
</script>
```

Is there anyway I can pass the picker_email to the JSP...so the outcome would be :

...

```
value = document.getElementById(picker_email).value;
<%
DatabaseHelper db_h = new DatabaseHelper();
boolean email_exists = db_h.verifyEmail( value );
%>

if( <%email_exists%> )
   proceedToServlet();
else
   alert( "INVALID EMAIL ");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're confused on how JSP and Javascript work together. JSP runs first on the server, outputting the HMTL.  Then the Javascript runs in the user's browser after the HTML has all been built and sent off to the user.  To get JSP to do something again, either have the user submit a normal HTML form, or use Ajax to call the server.

Answer (score 0):

@user2747139 developerwjk is correct. Why don't you try some ajax call to server. Writing scriptlet in jsp (Especially for server oriented purpose) is not a good practice. Here is some snippet. All you need to do is include jquery plugin in your jsp page. You can try like this,

```
function updateUserData(){ 
 var value = $("#picker_email").val();  
 $.ajax({
 url: "ur_servlet_url&value="+value,              
 type: "POST", 
 success: function(data){

  //If you want to return anything in jsp.
alert("Invalid Email");
   } 
 });
}
```

You do your validation in server side. If the validation succeeds/not succeeds return some text like `success` or `failure`. Based on this you will get response data in ajax. You can do alert `if(data == 'failure')` then `alert('Invalid Email');`. Let me know if this helps.